# C# Regex replace mutliple backslash(`\`) with single

Tags: c#, regex

I want to replace all occurences of multiple slash ('') with single backslash

For example

```
mama\\\\Please\\\\\U0U0001f973\U00.txt

Result  should be this
mama\Please\U0U0001f973\U00.txt
```

I have tried

```
string file = "mama\\\\Please\\\\\U0U0001f973\U00.txt"
string output = Regex.Replace(file, @"[/\\]{2,}", @"\");
```

current result

```
mama\\Please\\\U0U0001f973\U00.txt
```

Comment: You could use `(\\)+\1` and replace it with two back slashes, or how many slashes you need

Comment: See https://ideone.com/t7Fx3T, your code almost works if you define the string properly.

Comment: Like this? https://dotnetfiddle.net/SDCS1C